# useNavigate() breaks the hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made a simple react hook.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SearchReq(searchTerm: string) {
  if (searchTerm === "") return;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  console.log(searchTerm);
  // window.location.href = "/search?searchTerm=" + searchTerm;
  navigate("/search?searchTerm=" + searchTerm, { replace: true });
}
```

But for some reason it is giving me an error I had figured out that the line that is causing an error is `const navigate = useNavigate()` but I don't understand why can any one explain it to me?

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: What does "break the hook" means?

Comment: Ohh sorry I knew I forgot something, I had made an update with the error.